# What does the I in RWXI mean in the Softune Workbench linker file?

Tags: linker, softune

In the linker mapping file (.mp1) there is a column titled "Type" with `R`,`W`,`X`, and `I` as possible attributes, for example

```
RW--
R-XI
R---
R--I
```

Neither the manual, nor any other user guide mentions what these attributes mean. Checking my own code it is obvious that `R` means read, `W` means write, and `X` means code (executable), so for example, a variable is `RW-?`, a constant `R--?`, and a function `R-X?` Here I noted with `?` the presence or absence of `I`, for which I could not find any meaning.

Does anyone know what `I` in the `RWXI` means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Section 7.2.2 of this [manual](http://mcu.emea.fujitsu.com/document/sw_softune_workbench/documentation/SoftuneWorkbenchV6/documentation/softlnk-v6-cm71-00327-5e.pdf):

```
I/- Initial value Yes/No
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems the manual I read was too brief to include it. Still, I find it strange, why the `I` tag is present not only in `CONST` sections, but in `CODE` sections as well. I assumed it means that an area is initialized vs. containing undefined "garbage".